# Can no longer boot into ubuntu after updating

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have had my machine dual booting windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04 for many years using grub2. I havent been using ubuntu in awhile and have just logged back in. I had quite a lot of updates to do. Once I updated it told me I needed to restart to use the new version, I think it was a kernel update. I tried to reboot but I just get a black screen with a single line of green pixels going across the top of my monitor, no grub boot loader.
I can go into the bios and boot directly to windows 10 fine. But when I try ubuntu I just get the same black screen with the green line.
I decided to install ubuntu 18.04 from a live usb which was my original plan. On installation I told it to erase 16.04 and use that partition. It installed fine but I get the same problem with the black screen and green pixel line.

Windows an Ubuntu are on the same disk just different partitions. I have uefi

Any suggessions?

Comment: Graphics card? If Nvidia you probably need to install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Nvidia drivers needed for grub to load correctly? How would I install the drivers if I can't access the system